# Adding Javascript Listener Back After Removing In Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, httpwebrequest

I am testing a chrome extension.

How it's supposed to work is it blocks all requests except for the ones to google (or another domain)

The problem is when you go to Google.com, google makes subsequent requests and those are blocked, so I added the removeListener function.

The problem I'm having now is adding the listener back after I remove it. I thought it would happen after the window object finished loading, but I'm not sure I'm thinking about it correctly.

How could I add this listener back, or is there another way to solve this I'm not thinking of? Thank you.

```
var blocked_domains = [
"*://*/*"
];

var requestGuard = function(details) {
        if (details.url == "https://www.google.com/") {
            chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(requestGuard)
            return {cancel: false };
        } else {
            return {cancel: true };
        }
}

window.onload = chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    requestGuard, {urls: blocked_domains}, ["blocking"]
)
```

Comment: Why not set a flag on allowed domains, and pass through on you filter. Bind to the page load complete and reset the flag to being blocking again

Comment: The background page is a separate hidden page so its onload has no connection to the web pages. What you need is to check the request's tab URL and if it's Google's, allow the request: e.g. instead of `url` check `initiator` as you can see in the documentation. BTW your onload is incorrectly defined but since you don't need it simply remove `window.onload =`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @wOxxOm I was able to get this to work by reinitializing the listener after the webRequest completed. Here's what it looked like...

```
var blocked_domains = [
"*://*/*"
];

var requestGuard = function(details) {
        if (details.url == "https://www.google.com/") {
            chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(requestGuard)
            return {cancel: false };
        } else {
            return {cancel: true };
        }
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    requestGuard, {urls: blocked_domains}, ["blocking"]
)

chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function() {
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        requestGuard, {urls: blocked_domains}, ["blocking"]
    )
})
```

It could be written better, there's some duplication code, but it works